# iOS 6/7 deltas not visible on new xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I've started a new project in xcode as of a couple of weeks ago, tried setting it to target 6 and 7, but I still have no luck getting the ios 6/7 deltas to appear. I'm using the newest version of xcode, and I have seen the deltas in the inspector before on other projects.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this feature is hidden when you have autolayout on in your storyboard.

Comment: Right, the idea is that auto-layout can handle varying size of a UINavigationBar without knowing the iOS version.

Comment: What if I have a full screen background which has a 20px bar for the status bar in iOS 7?

Do I need to modify it to remove that bar?

Comment: That's a broader question than I can fully answer in a comment. But generally - you shouldn't have a separate background behind the status bar because that's not how iOS 7 is supposed to look. If you want to anyway, and you want its size to depend on iOS version, you can modify your constraints at runtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help - if you want me to, I can make a separate question for that so you can answer it, though I think I'll go ahead with your suggestion of removing the 20px bar.

Comment: No that's okay. Just make a separate question if you actually have more questions on this topic.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. I'm setting a constraint for the image to be 20px down from the top of the screen (I've also tried without) and the image is still under the status bar in iOS 7 20px below in iOS 6. What sort of constraint can I use which has a different effect on ios 6/7?

Answer (score 0):

To get "iOS6/7 Deltas" visible, make sure you turn off "Use Auto Layout" in the File Inspector.  Then, your Deltas should appear in the Size Inspector.

Now, this gets a little bit tricky - depending whether you're viewing the layout as "iOS 6.1 and earlier" or "iOS 7.0 or later" has an actual effect on your Delta values.

> 1. Choose "View as iOS 6.1 and Earlier"
> 2. Set the layout out as you want it to be
> 3. Now choose "View as iOS 7..", and the whole layout should be shifted up by 20 pixels    So it's off...however, make a note of the
>      fact that in iOS7 view, you want it to move down    by 20 pixels.
> 4. NB - Go back to "View as iOS 6.1 and Earlier", and the view looks OK again.
> 5. Now without changing anything, go to the Size Inspector, and in DeltaY, write 20.
> 6. Now if you view it as "iOS7...", the view should not be shifted.

The setting on "View as..." in The File Inspector has an effect on the actual value you need to write into the DeltaY fields .. same goes for DeltaHeight... or DeltaWidth...

Obviously, your status bar needs to be visible in order to see this inconsistency in the first place.